# How to access extended rule description through web API?

Tags: sonarqube

I'm using SonarQube 6.7.6. I try to access extended rule description through web API.

I access a rule which had [an extended description](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9yfHw.png) through the `api/rules/show` resource then I look at `htmlDesc` response field but this field doesn’t contain my extended description.

Does anyone know how to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I quote here the G Ann Campbell answer from SQ community forum:

> This is working for me in the latest version.
>   Speaking of which, 6.7.6 has some age on it at this point. The current version is 8.0 (8.1 to drop any day now) and the current LTS is 7.9.1. You should upgrade at your earliest convenience.

https://community.sonarsource.com/t/how-to-access-extended-rule-description-through-web-api/17500/2